# How to use Pandas DateTime to identify differences in time during EDA

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-difference

I have a couple of million DateTime objects in pandas. I could not find anything in the documentation for exploratory data analysis (EDA).

It looks like every single row has the same time  in either data frame:

DF1

Timestamp('2018-02-20 00:00:00')

or

DF2
   Timestamp('2018-01-01 05:00:00')

is there a way to use pandas to go through each column and check to see if there is a difference in the hours/minutes/seconds?

Everything I have found is about calculating differences between times.

I have tried a couple of basic techniques but all I get back are simple descriptive numbers.

```
min(data['date'])

data['date'].nunique()
```

I have tried:

```
 print(data['TIMESTAMP_UTC'])
```

Which does show some dates that have different hours, but I need a way to manage this information:

```
0         2018-01-16 05:00:00
1         2018-05-04 04:00:00
2         2018-10-22 04:00:00
3         2018-01-02 05:00:00
4         2018-01-03 05:00:00
5         2018-01-04 05:00:00
6         2018-01-05 05:00:00
......
```

Ideally,​ I am looking for something that could spit out a .value_counts() of dates that deviate from everything else

Comment: after you've checked the difference what do you want to do? can you post your sample input of both data frames, just a few rows. Also, what's linking the data frames, some sort of unique ID I presume?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.apply()` method to transform the format from `str` to `datetime`. Then you use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) to handle it.

To convert your column values into datetime :

```
df['TIMESTAMP_UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP_UTC'] )
df['TIMESTAMP_UTC'] = df['TIMESTAMP_UTC'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

then you can use the power of `datetime` to compare or extract information like this to extract hours for instance:

```
df['TIMESTAMP_UTC'].dt.day
```

Comment: Advoid using `apply` on series. Try `df['TIMESTAMP_UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP_UTC'] )` and `df['TIMESTAMP_UTC'].dt.day`.